# List of divs, inserting at additional div at location

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list of divs that I wish to include another div on the press of a button.  This position could be random, i.e, at the start, middle or bottom.

I have tried a number of ways but can't fathom it out. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

I have included a small sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    // This could be inserted at any point, i.e, start, middle or last;
    $(".bbc div").eq(2).prepend("<div>Appended item</div>");
  });

  $(".bbc div").click(function() {
    // On click return the eq() of the item;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bbc">
  <div>List item 1</div>
  <div>List item 2</div>
  <div>List item 3</div>
  <div>List item 4</div>
</div>
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?   How would the code know if it's supposed to be start middle or last?  Are you looking for a random number generator?

Comment: The current code inserts all divs inside another div, and I guess that is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job

```js
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', insertRandom);

function insertRandom() {
    const MAINPARENT = document.getElementsByClassName('bbc')[0],
        childsNum = MAINPARENT.querySelectorAll('div').length,
        randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * (childsNum+1));
        
    let elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = "NEW!!!!";

    if(randomPlace > childsNum){
        MAINPARENT.appendChild(elem);
    }
    MAINPARENT.insertBefore(elem, MAINPARENT.querySelectorAll('div')[randomPlace]);
}
```

```html
    <div class="bbc">
  <div>List item 1</div>
  <div>List item 2</div>
  <div>List item 3</div>
  <div>List item 4</div>
</div>

<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` for prepending at random location

```
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    const divLength = $(".bbc div").length;
    const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * divLength) + 1
    $(".bbc div").eq(randomInteger).prepend("<div>Appended item</div>");
  });
```

Updated solution: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRAA36XMXJUH

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using jQuery, try [insertBefore()](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/).

Comment: Before what? Link only answers are not well received here. See [answer]